# c# Post http request slow

Tags: c#

I am busy with a c# application that must upload data to a site. I use http post to upload the data but it is too slow for our application. It takes around 1.5 seconds to upload a small amount of data. I tried two different approaches.

Approach 1, using WebRequest:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(packet.url.ToString());
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.Proxy = null;
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(packet.postData);
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                dataStream.Close();
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
                dataStream.Close();
                response.Close();
```

Approach2, using WebClient:

```
string responseFromServer;
                using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                {
                    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    responseFromServer = wc.UploadString(packet.url, packet.postData);
                }
```

Both these have exactly the same delay. I tested the same thing in javascript. I used a xmlhttprequest to post the same data to the server and it took less than 0.5s to upload the data. Please let me know if there is a faster way of doing this in c#.

Comment: Was the C# and Javascript running on the same machine and network environment?

Comment: are you sure it's not a server issue?

Comment: Possible DNS lookup causing the slowness.

Comment: Both tests were done on the same machine to the same server.

Answer (score 0):

The attempt to first connection little slow, beside that rest other connection seems normal.

On first attempt to connect to a host, `HttpWebRequest` does a lot of work, it has to maintain a `ConnectionPool` and handle many other things. `HttpWebRequest` itself is very complicated.

Do not worry if only the first request goes slow.

Now, `xmlhttprequest` responds quickly because the browser tends to keep connection alive for any host that support it for a fair share amount of time. Hence the response is quicker!

Comment: Each time I upload data it takes approximately 1.5 to 2 seconds to upload data, not just the first time. Each time I need to send data I create a new WebRequest object. Is there a way of reusing the same object so that it maintains a ConnectionPool or does this automatically happen? Is there any advantage to using HttpWebRequest over WebRequest?

Comment: if you need faster response, try `System.Net.Socket` i have written a wrapper for myself and it is very fast!

Answer (score 0):

You should set `Proxy = null`, it increases the overall speed of all HTTP requests.

Comment: On the third line in approach 1 I set the Proxy to null. Unfortunately that did not make it faster

Answer (score 0):

You should send all amount of data in one request, as AppDeveloper said webrequest take a lot of time to initialize. I can offer you to do something like that:
As I think you have a - List and for each single postData you make a new web request. So you should parse whole List to JSON and then post complete List to server via WebRequest. It will take 2 seconds, but you will send whole data in that 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but this may suit you - `ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;`.